# insufficient privileges in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

i have created a table which is as belows .

[image]

The structure of the table is as follows :

```
Create Table advanced
 (Id  varchar(15),
 Name varchar(20),
 Dept  varchar(15),
 Cgpa  float,
 Birth_date date,
 Mob_no  int,
 Dist varchar(20),
 Salary  number(8));
```

When I want to create view as follows the sql plus gives me error 'insufficient privileges ' .

```
Create View advanced_data as
(
select name,dept,dist,salary from advanced
);
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: As a general rule, don't discard the ORA-... error code. It's a key tool to search for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems, that your user is not having permission for creating views.

To solve this follow these steps:
Login to sqlplus by sys user as sysdba and then run this command.

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO <user Name>;
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO <user Name>;
```

[Oracle DBA Blog](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031_insufficient_privileges.htm)
The ORA-01031: "insufficient privileges" error occurs when you attempt to execute a program or function for which you have not been granted the appropriate privileges.

For the DBA, the ORA-01031 can happen if the target OS executables do not have read and execute permissions (e.g. (770) in UNIX/Linux), and ensure that the oracle user is a member of the dba group (e.g. /etc/group).  There are similar permission in the Windows registry.

Inside Oracle, the "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" error can be avoided by signing on "as sysdba" with unlimited database privileges.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insifficient_privileges_create_view_grant.htm):

> To create a view, you must meet the following requirements:
>
> You must have been granted the CREATE VIEW (to create a view in your
>   schema) or CREATE ANY VIEW (to create a view in another user's schema)
>   system privilege, either explicitly or through a role.
>
> You must have been explicitly granted the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE object privileges on all base objects underlying the view or
>   the SELECT ANY TABLE, INSERT ANY TABLE, UPDATE ANY TABLE, or DELETE
>   ANY TABLE system privileges. You may not have obtained these
>   privileges through roles.
>
> Additionally, in order to grant other users access to your view, you
>   must have received object privilege(s) to the base objects with the
>   GRANT OPTION option or appropriate system privileges with the ADMIN
>   OPTION option. If you have not, grantees cannot access your view."

So you need to execute the below query to get the permission for the user to create a view:

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO username
```

The [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm#i2065510) also explicitly states that:

> The owner of the schema containing the view must have the privileges
>   necessary to either select, insert, update, or delete rows from all
>   the tables or views on which the view is based. **The owner must be
>   granted these privileges directly**, rather than through a role.